# Oracle hierarchical query with multiple roots returns childs as roots

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following data in a table:

```
ID  PID
B   A
C   B
D   B
E   D
G   F    
H   G
I   H
```

Here's a create/insert script for your convenience:

```
drop table hierarchic_test;

create table hierarchic_test(
     id varchar2(1),
     pid varchar2(1)
);

insert into hierarchic_test(id, pid) values('B', 'A');
insert into hierarchic_test(id, pid) values('C', 'B');
insert into hierarchic_test(id, pid) values('D', 'B');
insert into hierarchic_test(id, pid) values('E', 'D');
insert into hierarchic_test(id, pid) values('G', 'F');
insert into hierarchic_test(id, pid) values('H', 'G');
insert into hierarchic_test(id, pid) values('I', 'H');
```

Im trying to get a hierarchic query working on this data. My real data will contain multiple roots with multiple leaves. Start with is therefore not an option.

This is what I have so far, scrapped together from the documentation I found online:

```
select level, hierarchic_test.* from hierarchic_test
connect by prior hierarchic_test.id      = hierarchic_test.pid
order siblings by hierarchic_test.id
```

results I'm getting:

```
LEVEL ID   PID
1     B    A
2     C    B
2     D    B
3     E    D
1     C    B
1     D    B
2     E    D
1     E    D
1     G    F
2     H    G
3     I    H
1     H    G
2     I    H
1     I    H
```

The results I'm expecting should look like this:

```
LEVEL ID    PID
1     B     A
2     C     B
2     D     B
3     E     D
1     G     F
2     H     G
3     I     H
```

That also seems to be the documenten behavior over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm). If I use start with:

```
select level, hierarchic_test.* from hierarchic_test
start with hierarchic_test.id = 'A'
connect by prior hierarchic_test.id      = hierarchic_test.pid
order siblings by hierarchic_test.id
```

I DO get the results I want, but in my real data there will be mutliple roots and therefore I can't use start with. Can you point out my mistake/point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query:

```
select level,
       hierarchic_test.*
from   hierarchic_test
connect by prior hierarchic_test.id      = hierarchic_test.pid
order siblings by hierarchic_test.id
```

Retrieves what you think are multiple duplicates because you have not told it what to `START WITH` so it will start with everything:

```
LEVEL ID     PID
----- ------ ------
1     B      A
1     C      A
└ 2   └ D    └ C
1     D      C
1     A      (null)
├ 2   ├ B    ├ A
└ 2   └ C    └ A
  └ 3   └ D    └ C
```

With some added emphasis on the hierarchical structure it is easy to see that each of the four rows of the table has been chosen as the root of the hierarchy and this is why you have "duplicate" rows.

If you only want to `START WITH` the rows that do not have a corresponding parent row then:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/516c6d/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table hierarchic_test( id,  pid ) AS
  SELECT 'A', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F', 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'G', 'F' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT level,
       h.*
FROM   hierarchic_test h
START WITH pid IS NULL
OR         pid NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM hierarchic_test )
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = pid
ORDER SIBLINGS BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/516c6d/1/0)**:

```
| LEVEL | ID |    PID |
|-------|----|--------|
|     1 |  A | (null) |
|     2 |  B |      A |
|     2 |  C |      A |
|     3 |  D |      C |
|     1 |  F |      E |
|     2 |  G |      F |
```

Comment: This might be it. Got it to work aswell with `select level, hierarchic_test.* from hierarchic_test
start with hierarchic_test.id IN (
    select hierarchic_test.id from hierarchic_test
    left join hierarchic_test parent_hierarchic_test
    on parent_hierarchic_test.id = hierarchic_test.pid
    where parent_hierarchic_test.id is null
   -- order by hierarchic_test.id
)
connect by prior hierarchic_test.id      = hierarchic_test.pid
order siblings by hierarchic_test.id`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use multiple nodes to start with, if you craft some query that returns multiple values and you put it inside an `IN (...)`:

```
select level, hierarchic_test.* from hierarchic_test
start with hierarchic_test.id IN (
  SELECT 'A' AS start_candidate FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'WHATEVER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  ...
)
connect by prior hierarchic_test.id = hierarchic_test.pid
order siblings by hierarchic_test.id
```

Or if PID being null is always a starting node:

```
select level, hierarchic_test.* from hierarchic_test
start with hierarchic_test.pid IS NULL
connect by prior hierarchic_test.id = hierarchic_test.pid
order siblings by hierarchic_test.id
```

The first form allows you to pick exactly which nodes to start with, the latter relies on some common property of nodes

Comment: I can't use start with this way. In the real data the pid is not null and I can't do a subselect to get the highest level parents. That is what this query is supposed to do, allong with getting the hierarchic children.

Comment: Updated the question.